# Does execve reset GP registers?

Tags: c, executable

Does `execve()` or any of its sister functions reset the general-purpose registers? In other words, if the caller stores some values in all or some GPRs, will the new program see the same values in the same registers? Lets us assume that we deal with the IA64 architecture and GLIBC if it matters.

P.S. Questions on *development on Ubuntu* are on topic on this site. Please explain your downvote(s).